# Regge theory and $SU(3)$ mass formula

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics

In a [video interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lXipNMoS8o), Murray Gell-Mann states (at 40 seconds)

> "I have wondered all this time, and I still wonder, whether the straightness of those [Regge] trajectories, and the accuracy of the first-order mass formula for [flavor] $SU(3)$, aren't somehow related to each other. Both are a little bit surprising."

Has this question been addressed, anywhere in the physics literature?

Comment: Well, yeah, the hit-or-miss empirical phenomenology game never really died... See [Goldman & Buratovski 1997](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9708498)...

Comment: [Here](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.56.7119) and references therein... [and](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.61.054013) ...

Comment: [Remotely related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262248/derivation-of-gell-mann-okubo-relation-for-mesons)?